# Sequence definition of continuity for function on $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

The usual definition for continuous function $f:A\to\mathbb R$ is: if $x_n$ converge to $x$ then $f(x_n)$ converge to $f(x)$.

Let $A=\mathbb R^\mathbb N$, what will be the sequence definition of continuity be like?

I am guessing that we have to assume a strong condition that:

> if $x_n$ pointwise converge to $x$ then $f(x_n)$ converge to $f(x)$.

For example, the following definition is too weak to make $f$ continuous:

> $x_n$ uniformly converge imply $f(x_n)$ converge.

Am I correct? I could be wrong.

The key point of this question is the epsilon-delta definition of continuity stays the same, but we have to extra careful when considering the sequence definition.

Comment: "Converge" and "pointwise converge" mean the same thing usually. The definition of sequential continuity doesn't change in higher dimensions, and indeed generalizes to any context where sequences exist (importantly being equivalent to continuity in all metric spaces, including $\mathbb R^n$)

Comment: *Provided* your topology on $\Bbb R^\Bbb N$ is the product topology, i.e. the topology of pointwise convergence, your "guess" is obviously correct for the definition of [*sequential* continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Sequences_and_nets).